# jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?)

Tags: json, jq

```
type sols3json.json | jq-win64.exe  "[.[] | { "type": "FeatureCollection","features":[{  type: "Feature", "geometry":  {"type": "LineString","coordinates":  [  [.OpStartLongitude, .OpStartLatitude| tonumber],  [ .OpEndLongitude, .OpEndLatitude | tonumber] ]  },  properties: {name: .SolName}}]}"  > sols3.geojson
```

I get jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?)
What am I doing wrong?
The output should be like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": 
    [
    {
    "properties": {
    "ccaa": "CATALUNYA",
    "prov": "LLEIDA",
    "dir": "N-IIA/SOSES/TORRES DE SEGRE/ALCARRàS",
    "roadnumber": "A-2",
    "tmc": "E17+02413"
    },
    "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
    [
    0.4714937,
    41.5420936
    ],
    [
    0.4891472,
    41.5497014
    ]
    ],
    "type": "LineString"
    },
    "type": "Feature"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing square bracket `]` at the end of the filter

Comment: In order to check if your filter does something useful, please add the content of the file `sols3json.json` in question.

Comment: If I add it I get jq: error: FeatureCollection/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:

Comment: The file contains data in this format: {
"TMC": "E17+02412",
"ROADNUMBER": "A-2",
"DIR": "E-90/AP-2/BARCELONA-ZARAGOZA (SOSES)",
"PROV": "LLEIDA",
"CCAA": "CATALUNYA",
"StartLatitude": "41.5368273",
"StartLongitude": "0.4387071",
"EndLatitude": "41.5388396",
"EndLongitude": "0.4638462"
} but with different names for the properties

Comment: I am trying to do this https://doublebyteblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/csv-2-geojson/

Comment: You should *update your question* with the exact format you want to have. Linking an external page is not the right way to ask a good question

Answer (score -1):

Your question is rather unclear, but yet I understand correctly, this is likely what you want.

Provided your input file is:

```
[
  {
    "TMC": "E17+02412",
    "ROADNUMBER": "A-2",
    "DIR": "E-90/AP-2/BARCELONA-ZARAGOZA (SOSES)",
    "PROV": "LLEIDA",
    "CCAA": "CATALUNYA",
    "StartLatitude": "41.5368273",
    "StartLongitude": "0.4387071",
    "EndLatitude": "41.5388396",
    "EndLongitude": "0.4638462"
  }
]
```

You can filter the content using this `jq` filter:

```
jq 'map({ type: "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "LineString","coordinates": [ [.StartLongitude, .StartLatitude| tonumber], [ .EndLongitude, .EndLatitude | tonumber] ] }, properties: {tmc: .TMC, roadnumber: .ROADNUMBER, dir: .DIR, prov: .PROV, ccaa: .CCAA}})' file
```

resulting in this new JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          0.4387071,
          41.5368273
        ],
        [
          0.4638462,
          41.5388396
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "tmc": "E17+02412",
      "roadnumber": "A-2",
      "dir": "E-90/AP-2/BARCELONA-ZARAGOZA (SOSES)",
      "prov": "LLEIDA",
      "ccaa": "CATALUNYA"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Well that would be true but I need to create a FeatureCollection (because I have multiple records like described here https://doublebyteblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/csv-2-geojson/  ).

Comment: so the complete json input format is like this [ {
  "TMC": "E17+02412",
  "ROADNUMBER": "A-2",
  "DIR": "E-90/AP-2/BARCELONA-ZARAGOZA (SOSES)",
  "PROV": "LLEIDA",
  "CCAA": "CATALUNYA",
  "StartLatitude": "41.5368273",
  "StartLongitude": "0.4387071",
  "EndLatitude": "41.5388396",
  "EndLongitude": "0.4638462"
} ]